# Remove specific characters from a list (Python3)

Tags: python, string, list

There is a list:

> name = [('Ferdinand',)]

And i want to get this:

> 'Ferdinand'

What should i do?

Comment: `name[0][0]`?...

Comment: print(name) does not return what you desire?

Comment: That's a tuple inside a list. A [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) can be treated as a read-only list.  Here you want the first item in the list at index 0 (which yields the tuple) and the first item of the tuple at index 0. In other words, `name[0][0]`.  But really, that's basic Python. I encourage you to reread the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

You have a single element `tuple` inside a `list`. To simply set your variable `name` to a `string`: `Ferdinand` you can use

```
name = name[0][0]
```

If you ever have a situation where you have more than one `string` inside the `tuple` this would be one way you can access a full `string` representation of them:

```
names = [('Ferdinand','surname'),('John','surname')]
for tup in names:
    full_name = " ".join(tup)
```